# Key fob receiver reverse engineering: IC identification

Tags: rf, rfid, reverse-engineering

I'm doing reverse engineering on a hardware of an equipment, this equipment is able to identify the presence of a RF signal from a key fob.

Unfortunately, it was not possible to identify the integrated circuit, it has a mask, a number that makes no sense to me and I was not able to find information about it.

I don't know either the exactly values of the capacitors, I cannot remove them from the circuit. So, I would like to know, based on the incomplete information of the figure below, could someone identify, or make a guess, about which integrated it would be?

[image]

Below is the image of the antenna of the circuit. The other circuit components are on the other side of the board

[image]

**EDITED:** 
Below is the image of the IC, the code printed on it surface:

506

1403

M83

[image]

PS: Sorry for the lack of information in the question, any information or guess may be valid.

Comment: do you have a picture of the IC? Generally, I think without proper IC markings, you'll be out of luck, unless you start reverse-engineering the RF signal yourself: there's **a lot** of cheap receiver ICs

Comment: Whatever it is, it won't be anything as simple as a "frequency meter."  The fob will transmit data on the radio signal.  Your IC will receive the signal and decode the data.

Comment: You need to post a picture of the IC, and write out the numbers printed on it as best you can decipher them.

Comment: Also "the number makes no sense to me": well, it might make sense to someone else, that's why you're asking, right? so, what's the number?

Comment: @MarcusMüller. Sorry, I thought number was made to no one to know. But youre right, I edited the post and add a picture and the numbers. They are: 506  1403  M83

Comment: @Daniel sadly, you were a bit right, and that number doesn't strike much of a bell with me, but the picture says "IC without even a manufacturer logo", so chances are this is something extremely low-cost; maybe some old analog IC, which would explain the custom packaging.

Comment: @Daniel so I'm worried your reverse engineering efforts come to an unfortunate halt here. Maybe there's better ways to achieve what you want to achieve: what's the reason you're reverse-engineering this circuit?

Comment: @MarcusMüller  I need to identify the frequency of Key fobs. Some of them has 433Mhz others has different frequencies and I need to differentiate them.

Comment: @Daniel that sounds like you don't need to reverse engineer the hardware at all. OK, maybe an analysis of the antenna would bring you forward in guessing the frequency, but really, this is a job for 10€ SDR dongle and a laptop.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Nice, I need to add this functionality in a hardware that do other things besides to recognize frequencies. A dongle can be a good idea, I will search for something similar since not  too expensive

Comment: get an RTL-SDR dongle, and use it with gqrx to simply look for signals. It's actually fun to hunt for signals! Once you've got them recorded, `inspectrum` is a great tool to actually detect modulation, and extract bits.